# Optimal query to select nth row in MySQL

Tags: mysql, query-performance

I have a huge table ( > 1 billion rows) and want to select nth row (example 100 millionth row), if i use this query :

`SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY indexed_column ASC LIMIT 1 OFFSET 100,000,000`,

result is OK but **performance is not** ! Because this query should scan 100,000,000 row to select 100 millionth row and the table will be locked during this process.

Is there any **optimal query** to select nth row in MySQL?

Comment: https://explainextended.com/2009/10/23/mysql-order-by-limit-performance-late-row-lookups/

Comment: There's no general way to do what you want quickly. If we knew the structure of your table maybe we could suggest some specific way. Please read this https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/ and then [edit] your question to provide more information.  And, you should know that `SELECT *` is a notorious performance antipattern. Try naming only the columns you need in your result.

Comment: What version of MySQL?

Comment: Is `indexed_column` the `PRIMARY KEY`?

Comment: MySQL 5.6 and indexed_column is PRIMARY_KEY

Answer (score 0):

You can replace your offset keyword for limit, and force index usage for better result.

```
SELECT * FROM table FORCE INDEX (index_name) ORDER BY indexed_column ASC LIMIT 100000000, 1;
```

Performance should be better, but you need to check how much.

I've made an assumption you have to select all the fields from `table`. If it's wrong, try to select only what you need.